# How can I show that this limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus

I have a doubt in an exercise of Calculus De Michal Spivak, I would appreciate any attempt.

11.34 a) (a) Give an example of a function f for which $lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$  exists, but $lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)$    does not exist.

Solution: Let $  $$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x^2}{x}$

$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\sin \left(x^2\right)}{x}\right)=0$

But How can I prove     $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2x^2\cos \:\left(x^2\right)-\sin \:\left(x^2\right)}{x^2}\right)$. No exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2x^2\cos \:\left(x^2\right)-\sin \:\left(x^2\right)}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}2\cos(x^2)-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}2\cos(x^2)$. What happens with $cos(x^2)$ as $x$ approaches infinity? Well, is not defined. Take $x_n=\sqrt{\pi(2n+1)}$ and $y_n=\sqrt{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}}$ Bot of them go to infinity as $n\to\infty$ but
$$cos(x_n^2)=-1\;,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ while
$$cos(y_n^2)=0\;,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to formally demonstrate why it does not exist, greetings.

Comment: Do you fully understand my reasoning? :)

Comment: Yes, it is the definition that the limit does not exist through sequence, but could you do the same with $\epsilon$ $ and $\delta$ ?

Comment: The limit of a sum is not necessarily equal to the sum of the limits.  So, you cannot decompose arbirarily as you did here.  You can say is that if the limit of the sum exists than it must be equal to the sum of the limits.

Comment: yes, by contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the limit exists and is equal to $L$. In that case we have that
$$
L = 2\lim_{x\to \infty}\cos (x^2)-\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin x^2}{x^2} = 2\lim_{x\to \infty}\cos (x^2)
$$

However, since and the last limit does not exist, we have reached a contradiction and conclude that the original limit cannot exist.

Comment: @MarkViola I am not decomposing arbitrarily... I am assuming that the limit exists and extracting the consequences. If $\lim (f+g)$ exists and $\lim g = 0$ you can surely claim that $\lim(f+g) = \lim f$. In this case, if you assume the limit exists, you conclude that it must be equal to a limit that does not exist, hence ...

Comment: @MarkViola Popint taken, I've added to the answer.